# Angular - ngzone logic for inside vs outside - signalr sample

Tags: angular

I have a simple application in angular >= 2 that uses signalr. I have a problem thou with understanding how to determine weather certain things will be executed inside ngzone or outside. The code below will for all signalr stuff be outside of ngzone if I reload the page on this route. If I load page in another route that is completely empty & from there navigate to below code it will be executed inside ngzone.

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Subscription }    from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { BehaviorSubject }    from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-data-page',
  templateUrl: './data-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-page.component.less']
})
export class DataPageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  public title = 'Bug report!';
  public data = new Array<any>();

  private subscription: Subscription;
  private connection: SignalR.Hub.Connection;
  private counter:number = 1;
  private secretData = new Map<number, any>();
  private dataSubject = new BehaviorSubject(this.secretData);

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(`ngOnInit: ${NgZone.isInAngularZone()}`);
    this.subscription = this.dataSubject.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(`subscribe: ${NgZone.isInAngularZone()}`);
      this.data = new Array<any>();
      data.forEach((d) => {
        this.data.push(d);
      });
    }); 

    let uri = 'http://localhost:8080/fake/signalr';
    let c =  $.hubConnection(uri, { useDefaultPath: false });
    this.connection = c;
    c.logging = true;
    let hub = c.createHubProxy('myHub');
    hub.on('tick', () => {
      console.log(`tick: ${NgZone.isInAngularZone()}`);
      this.generateData();
    });
    c.start().always(() => 
    {
      console.log(`Calling getData: ${NgZone.isInAngularZone()}`);
      hub.invoke('getData')
        .always(() => {
          console.log(`getData: ${NgZone.isInAngularZone()}`);
          this.generateData();
        });
    });


    // this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/fake/api/getData").subscribe(() => {
    //   this.generateData();
    // }, (error) => {
    //   this.generateData();
    // });

    // setTimeout(() => {
    //  this.generateData();
    // }, 100);
  }



  ngOnDestroy() {    
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    this.connection.stop();
  }

    private generateData() {
      let end = this.counter+2;
      for(let i = this.counter; i < end; i++) {
        var d = { id: this.counter, name: "" + this.counter };
        this.secretData.set(d.id, d);
        this.counter++;
      }
      this.dataSubject.next(this.secretData);
  }
}
```

The second part of the question is what is the proper fix for this (there are multiple mechanism for change detection)? My actual code for this is in a service rather than a component & i guess the proper fix is injecting a zone & using zone.run at some place - since service probably shouldn't trigger an gui detection update.

Sample angular frontend project:
http://www.filedropper.com/angular-app

Edit to run:
npm install
ng serve

Edit:
If running the creation with a setTimeout e.g. 2000 ms it will be inside. So some type of timing issue that I would like explained.

```
    setTimeout(() => 
    {
// Works everything will be inside zone
        this.connect();
    }, 0);

// callbacks in the connect will be outside
    this.connect();
```

Where connect is refactored out from above

```
  private connect() {
    let uri = 'http://localhost:8080/fake/signalr';
        let c =  $.hubConnection(uri, { useDefaultPath: false });
        this.connection = c;
        c.logging = true;
        let hub = c.createHubProxy('myHub');
        hub.on('tick', () => {
          console.log(`tick: ${NgZone.isInAngularZone()}`);
          this.generateData();
        });
        c.start().always(() => 
        {
          console.log(`Calling getData: ${NgZone.isInAngularZone()}`);
          hub.invoke('getData')
            .always(() => {
              console.log(`getData: ${NgZone.isInAngularZone()}`);
              this.generateData();
            });
        });
}
```

Comment: by default any code triggered by Angular is executed in angular zone. Your question is not very clear. Could you reduce your code to the minimum and create a plnkr to be able to see the problem?

Comment: how do you include signalr in plnkr?
http://www.filedropper.com/angular-app but it does not include signalr backend just frontend

Comment: any ideas at all? Method is in zone and dispatching with setTimeout makes its callback become in zone otherwise not. Or link to documentation describing when you become outside of zone - seen brians video linked from angular doc & excellent article https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/22/understanding-zones.html but none gives any warning or information that explains this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## When async operations are run inside the Angular Zone

When your Angular Component uses a timer (`setTimeout`) to call a function, it is captured in the Angular Zone by `NgZone` to trigger change detection. Likewise, if you make a WebSocket connection inside an Angular declarable, it will be captured in the Angular Zone.

## When and why SignalR is different

The reason that connecting SignalR synchronously in the component method does not make it run inside the Angular Zone is that SignalR is using a **real**, i.e. non-`Zone`d `window.WebSocket` or some other async communication channel, not one registered in the NgZone.

## Drawing parallels to AngularJS

If you are familiar with AngularJS, the equivalent of your example is that your Angular Component is using `$timeout` while the SignalR client by itself is using the native `setTimeout`.

## Beware when running server push in the Angular Zone

While you can run SignalR messages inside the Angular zone, it seems that [runnning every async message from a server push source (like WebSocket and SignalR) in the Angular Zone can easily result in performance issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44371180/1071200).

## Additional reading

If you would like to know more about Zone.js and NgZone, here are some valuable resources:

- [Understanding NgZone](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-ngzone) by Tiago Roldao
- [The `run*` methods of `NgZone`](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone) at Angular API docs
- [Do you still think that NgZone (zone.js) is required for change detection in Angular?](https://blog.angularindepth.com/do-you-still-think-that-ngzone-zone-js-is-required-for-change-detection-in-angular-16f7a575afef) by Max “NgWizard” K
- [What the hell is Zone.js and why is it in my Angular 2?](https://medium.com/@MertzAlertz/what-the-hell-is-zone-js-and-why-is-it-in-my-angular-2-6ff28bcf943e) by Pete Mertz
- [`setTimeout` test suite](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/master/test/common/setTimeout.spec.ts) at Zone.js